# can't make new project with wasm-pack new myProjectName

Tags: rust, rust-wasm, wasm-pack

```
ewmacfarland@Erics-MacBook-Air wasm-crypto % wasm-pack new crypto
Error: expected value at line 1 column 1
Caused by: expected value at line 1 column 1
```

tried un and reinstalling it every way i could

run on M1 chip

Comment: Per [this issue](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack/issues/1266) the current version is broken, and you need to downgrade to v0.10.3

Comment: how do i downgrade

Comment: Added in an answer so it's more visible to other users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [this issue](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack/issues/1266) it's a problem in wasm-pack, and the solution for the moment is to downgrade to 0.10.3.

How you do that depends on how you installed it. If you installed from npm, `npm i -g wasm-pack@0.10.3`. If you used cargo, `cargo install --version 0.10.3 wasm-pack`. If you installed using the shell script on the website, it looks like their gh-pages build process overwrites that branch for some reason, so you'll need to [copy the script](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack/blob/gh-pages/installer/init.sh) and modify the references to 0.11.0 to read 0.10.3, then run it.